# How to update Blackduck findings on angular 8.3.29

Tags: angular-cli

I need to update a lot of packages from my Angular project, cause I have a blackduck report to solve,

My angular version is

```
 _                      _                 ____ _     ___
/ \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
```

/ △ \ | '_ \ /  *`| | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
/ ___ | | | | (*| | |*| | | (*| | |      | |***| |*** | |
/*/   __| |*|_*, |_*,*|*|_*,*|*|       _***|*****|***|
|___/

Angular CLI: 8.3.29
Node: 12.21.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14

```
Package                            Version
@angular-devkit/architect          0.801.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.801.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.801.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.801.3
@angular-devkit/core               8.1.3
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.29
@angular/cdk                       8.2.3
@angular/cli                       8.3.29
@angular/material                  8.2.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter   10.2.7
@ngtools/webpack                   8.1.3
@schematics/angular                8.3.29
@schematics/update                 0.803.29
rxjs                               6.4.0
typescript                         3.4.5
webpack                            4.35.2
```

Then,

The report raise the below incident `faye-websocket-node:0.10.0:3`, but I dont know hot to solve this issue,

Comment: npm-check can be used for bulk-updating through the terminal:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check

Answer (score 0):

You can't update all package at one shot.

You can use `ng update --force allowDirty`

It will list up new upgradable packages.

After that you can do

`npm install package-name@version && npm install package-name@version && npm install package-name@version`

You can use `--force` to avoid errors